# How does ohm's law for capacitors affect this scenario?

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis

Ohm's law for capacitors is i = C dv/dt

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjQz0l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Clearly there's a zero change in voltage across C1 always, but since C1 is a capacitor, it can hold charge and the current is not zero.

Comment: Do they call that ohm's law for capacitors now? I've not seen it called that before.

Comment: Voltage change is also zero so current is zero.

Comment: Since the voltage across the capacitor is zero, the charge (=CV) is also zero.

Comment: @Justme But wouldn't current still flow because there's space in the capacitor to store charge?

Comment: The short cct. Dumps any/all charge and is actually dissipated in the electrode resistance ESR. With a time constant of C*ESR

Comment: In this _theoretical_ circuit, the capacitor has the same node at both ends so it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Hearth Why not it is an Ohm's law ? That equation is derived from standard Ohm's law representation in laplace domain:

 I(s).1/sC = V(s) , 

where 1/sC is the impedance of capacitor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact of the matter is that both ends of C1 are connected to the same equivalent node (shorted). At steady-state, there is certainly no current flow, because there is no difference in potential on either side of C1.

To make this more clear: You cited `i = C dv/dt`. "dv" means difference/change in voltage. But there cannot be a difference in voltage if both ends of C1 are the same equivalent node with 0Ω between.

If there were a charge on C1 before both ends were shorted, then upon shorting, the current would flow (but with theoretical 0 Ω wire, the drain would would be instantaneous / infinite current).